# Can a question be marked duplicate even if the "original" question has no answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

Can question 2 be marked duplicate of question 1, even though question 1 has literally no answer?

Edit- On Stack overflow

Comment: On SO? No. On Meta.SO? Yes. Basically, an answer has to have been posted on an SO question for it to be used as a target to close other questions as dupes of. On Meta.SO, there does not have to be an answer to the question yours is closed as a dupe of. So, it depends on which side you're talking about. :)

Comment: On both, yes. On meta without restrictions, on main only with the same author.

Comment: On Stack overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On meta, any question can be marked duplicate of any other without restriction (aside from cycles).

On main, the duplicate-target must be answered or by the same author.