# Edit to question (within the 5 minute window) doesn't unlock downvote

Tags: bug, grace-period, locked-votes

I downvoted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341025/tree-searching-algorithm-how-to-determine-quickly-if-a-has-a-sure-to-win-strate) based on its bad title (it's fixed now), OP fixed it and commented saying "Edited, is it good now?", I wanted to remove the downvote but I couldn't - I got the tooltip saying my vote was locked until the question is edited, **even though it had been edited after my vote**.

Turns out the edit was close enough to be "merged", within the 5 minutes window, so the revision history didn't show it. So maybe that's why the vote was locked.

Comment: They say it's status-by-design, but it really is more like bug. It's unexpected behavior from a user's point of view.

Comment: Technically, none of the linked question have an answer. I had to crawl among all comments and related MSE posts to find that 1. One of the [posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256606/3545273) is a feature request since  May 29 '142, upvoted 34/0 but nothing saying if is is regarded  2. there is (was ?) a quick and dirty workaround [Just edit the answer yourself, then roll it back...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78444) -- I answer myself with that link http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278361/3545273

Comment: @SergeBallesta I just added a newline at the end. No need to roll it back :)